# How to fix 'OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError' error in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use CloudFlare Flexible SSL certificate.

When I try send user registration confirmation, I receive 500 error. In log:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol):

My **production.rb**:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
tls: true,
    address: 'smtp.yandex.ru',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'yandex.ru',
    authentication: 'plain',
    user_name: 'admin@site.ru',
    password: 'password',
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Hope you have configured SSL key and cert. Then use the config to start the server. If you don't know or haven't done this step then google to look up a tutorial. :)

Comment: I configured SSL certificate in CloudFlare panel. Don't use server for configured. In apache rules i use redirect to https and it work's.

Comment: I meant set up SSL for puma or whatever rails server you are using.

Comment: I do not have certificate files because the CloudFlare does not issue them

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the SSL certificate on your server, nor cloudflare. Your settings look correct for typical SMTP+STARTTLS servers, so I’d say you need some lower-level debug logging or some other analysis tools like testssl.sh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error usually occurs if you try to establish an encrypted connection to a server that doesn't expect this. Port 587 typically requires the use of `STARTTLS` after first establishing an unecrypted connection. Try removing `tls: true` in your configuration and using `enable_starttls_auto: true` instead.

Comment: Could you add a longer excerpt from your log? Is there a backtrace by any chance?

Comment: Now error: `Net::SMTPFatalError (553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.`

Comment: This means that your mailer is trying send from an invalid source address. Try adding `default from: 'youraccount@example.com'`, using your `yandex.ru` mail address.

Comment: The problem was that a completely different mail was used at **devise.rb**, changing it all worked.